# Do I have to escape this search $q input? (for sql injection)

Tags: magento2, database, sql

In Magento2 I have a Collection method for a search function like this:

```
 /**
     * @param string $q
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addSearchFilter($q)
    {
        $this->addFieldToFilter(
                array('title', 'content'),
                array(
                    array('like' => '%' . $q . '%'),
                    array('like' => '%' . $q . '%')
                )
            );
        return $this;
    }
```

My question is: is this safe? Or do I need to escape $q to prevent sql injection?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can safely use this function without any escape on your side.

At the end of this function Magento call

> public function prepareSqlCondition($fieldName, $condition)

and all passed variables quote by Zend.

As a result you get safely sql string

[image]

Comment: You are back!!!